# Strange behavior with tsquery in PostgreSQL with prefix-lexemes

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

When I use 'a:*' (also 'i:*', 's:*', 't:*')

```
SELECT id FROM mv_fulltextsearch1 WHERE to_tsvector(text) @@ to_tsquery('a:*') LIMIT 50;
```

Takes forever and prints the following PostgreSQL output a lot

```
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
```

But when I use 'b:*' (same with any other single letter in front of ':*')

```
SELECT id FROM mv_fulltextsearch1 WHERE to_tsvector(text) @@ to_tsquery('b:*') LIMIT 50;
```

everything is OK

Are a, i, s and t some kind of special characters? How can I escape them / fix the strange behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `to_tsvector('simple', text)` and `to_tsquery('simple', 'a:*')`

The reason is that the 'english' regconfig removes [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) and "a" is considered a stop word

However, the 'simple' regconfig does not remove stop words

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#textsearch-parsing-queries

> Also, * can be attached to a lexeme to specify prefix matching:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES

> while basic tsquery input takes the tokens at face value, to_tsquery
>   normalizes each token into a lexeme using the specified or default
>   configuration, and discards any tokens that are stop words according
>   to the configuration.

which leads me to a conclusion that your `to_tsquery` throws **a** and **I** as stop words, staying with NO TEXT to query... (see the example with `the rat and cat` in docs above)

(((Please dont ask what stop word is **t**)))

eg, if you (no `to_tsquery` and thus stop words not thrown away)

```
with c(t) as (values('a an also at bond'),('but by illegal'),('I in it aligator'))
select t,to_tsvector(t) @@ ('a:*')::tsquery from c;

         t         | ?column?
-------------------+----------
 a an also at bond | t
 but by illegal    | f
 I in it aligator  | t
(3 rows)
```

it will work...

for reference on stop words:

```
-bash-4.2$ grep "^t$" /usr/share/pgsql93/tsearch_data/english.stop
t
```

**t** is the one... but my modest knowledge of English lacks understanding why